# (Magento) Using variables from custom textfields in mailtemplate

Tags: email, templates, variables, magento

I used this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426242/how-to-create-new-fields-for-customer/8758970) to create custom textfields for a new guest order. The inputted value gets saved to the database but I can't figure how to use those values in an e-mail. (I'm using kvk instead of school in the example)

Tried some of these and a lot more:
{{var data.kvk}} {{var customer.Kvk}} {{var order.getCustomerKvk}}

Anyone who knows how to solve this?