# Magento - Customer Profile Photo upload

Tags: magento

I've been trying to find a way to add Photo to a customer profile in Magento.
They have everything but this, and I can't find anywhere how to do it.
Any help is appreciated.
I'm using Community edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upload profile photo for customer in magento we need to follow few steps as below.

- Add a new field for profile photo([How to create new fields for customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426242/how-to-create-new-fields-for-customer) - Check this link it will helps you).
- The above link helps you to add a new filed in DB and you need to upload that photo manually the below code will helps you to upload photos in magento.

  ```
                  if(isset($_FILES['logo']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']))) 
                  {

                    try {
                      $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('logo');
                      $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                      $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                      $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                      $path       = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'catalog/customer/logo/';
                      $newName    = time() . $_FILES['logo']['name'];
                      $uploader->save($path, $newName);
                      $customer->setLogo($newName);

                      // actual path of image
                      $imageUrl = $path . $newName;

                      // path of the resized image to be saved
                      // here, the resized image is saved in media/resized folder
                      $imageResized = $path . $newName;

                      // resize image only if the image file exists and the resized image file doesn't exist
                      // the image is resized proportionally with the width/height 135px
                      if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($imageUrl)) :
                          $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imageUrl);
                          $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
                          $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
                          $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
                          $imageObj->resize(150, 150);
                          $imageObj->save($imageResized);

                      endif;
                    }catch(Exception $e) {

                    }
                  }
  ```
- After upload we need to save file name in DB.

  $customer->setLogo($newName);

Comment: Hi Sankar. Thanks for the solution! I've put the code into my module's observer but whenever 'customer_save_before' or 'customer_save_after' event fires(within customer back-end) $_FILES array is empty. I get file name in $_POST array though but i don't get the $_FILES. Any ideas? Maybe you can suggest other place where I could put this code?

Comment: Ok, I got this. "Additional information" form needs enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute. Otherwise it won't submit files.